# Core Data Mapping Models

Tags: core-data, core-data-migration

Is there an easier way in Xcode to create mapping models.

Currently I'm on model 14 and having to create individual models from 1 to 14 is time consuming.

I've tried copying an older model and changing the destination but am unable to see any of the new fields added